my SQL Server SA account won't give me access (it doesn't log in)
I have three machines at home that I use for personal code development.  I installed SQL Server 16.0.1000.6 on all machines (all running Windows 11).  On all machines, it was installed using my personal Microsoft account, and everything appears to work fine but, as a consequence, the SA login was disabled.  However, I did have some issues with my Microsoft account on one machine which took MS Support some 4 hours to fix.  So I decided to enable the SA login as a backup in case the Microsoft account "went west".  On the first machine, it went fine, changed the SA password, and enabled the account.  Connected with SSMS as SQL Server  Authentication and I'm in!  However, on both the other two machines, if I try the same thing, it won't allow me to log in.  The messages say that SSMS can't connect to the machine (or even localhost - both of which work with the Microsoft Account) and thus the login fails.
Any ideas?  BTW, I used the same password for all three SA logins, but I figured that since the are local it would be OK.

Have you enabled mixed-mode (SQL server and Windows Auth) at the instance level?

Doh!  (Homer Simpson would be proud!).  I plead "Snow blindness" - trying to set up the same thing on three machines simultaneously.  The first, of course, was set up correctly, the next two weren't!  Thanks, @spikey_richie!

I’m voting to close this question because it was user error and it has been solved.

@RohitGupta there's a posted and valid answer. If this is a duplicate, it could be closed as that, but as there is a good answer, we don't need to close it.

As @spikey_richie said, make sure you have Mixed-mode authentication enabled!
